# Rotar Vector JAVA

Tags: java

tengo un codigo que genera caracteres aleatorios.Mi problema es que quiero presentar el vector rotado es decir vector={a,b,c,d};

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero presentar por pantalla asi, pero al compilar me salta un mensaje de error que no puedo solucionar,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.util.Random;
public class caracterAleatorio_Rotado {
```

Este metodo genera los caracteres aleatorios.

```
static char [] caracterAleatorio (int n){
    char caracter []=new char[n];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<caracter.length;i++){
        caracter[i]= (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        System.out.println(caracter[i]);
    }
    return caracter;
}
```

Este es el metodo que tengo creado para presentar y rotar el vector.

```
static void rotarVector(char caracter[]){
   char primero= caracter[0];
   for(int i=0;i<caracter.length;i++){
       primero=caracter[i+1];
       caracter[i+1]=caracter[0];
       caracter[0]=primero;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<caracter.length;i++){
       System.out.println(caracter[i]);
   }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char vector []=new char[7];
    System.out.println("****VECTOR NORMAL****");
    vector=caracterAleatorio (7);
    System.out.println("****VECTOR ROTADO****");
    rotarVector(vector);
}
```

}

Comment: recuerda que los indices parten de 0 si tu array es de tamaño 7 el utlimo indice sera 6 por ende i siendo 6 +1 dara 7 el cual es un indice que te lanza esa exception establece el primer for de tu método rotar de esta manera 'for(int i=0;i<caracter.length-1;i++)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static char[] rotarVector(char vector[]){
char vectorRotado [] = new char[vector.length];
int longitudVector = vector.length;

for(int i = 0; i < (longitudVector-1); i++){
    vectorRotado[i] = vector[i+1];
}
vectorRotado[longitudVector-1] = vector[0];
return vectorRotado; }
```

después si queres rotar más lugares a la derecha podes hacer otro método para ejecutar varias veces este código (básicamente un bucle).